# smbtree works only when iptables flush is provided.

Tags: tcp, samba, smb

Tried to run smbtree without iptables --flush, it is not providing any output.
When provided with iptables --flush, it is displaying workgroups and computers which is good.

So we tried to add port numbers used for smbtree(137,138,139 and 445) in iptables as below and given iptables-save and then tried smbtree without iptables --flush. In that case also it's not working.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 137:139 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 137:139 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 1025:65535 -j ACCEPT
```

any other way to debug or proceed further.